# Inserting Python list into SQL db

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I have a python list containing last_name, first_name, title 
I would like to insert this list into sql db, but the data should be inserted in 3 columns and many rows...
I tried following:

```
data = updated_values[7:-1] #list has around 200 names
query = "INSERT INTO names(last_name, first_name, titles) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(query,data)
```

but it throws error...
can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Do you think including the error that it throws would be helpful?

Comment: Also what does your data look like? Executemany docs say your data should be an array of values like this [(last_name, first_name, titles),(last_name, first_name, titles) ]

Comment: mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: my data looks some thing like this:   ['Klis', 'Martijn', 'nil', 'der', 'Sloot', 'Sander', 'nil', 'dns-admin', 'nil', 'nil', 'dns-admin', 'nil', 'nil', 'do', 'Prado', 'Arnaldo', 'nil', 'ernest', 'mark', 'nil', 'ernesto', 'chunguane', 'jose', 'nil', 'fischer', 'vicky', 'nil', 'friedman', 'hope', 'nil', 'fry', 'mark', 'nil', 'fuller', 'godfrey', 'nil', 'gao', 'xiaojun', 'nil', 'hachani', 'anis', 'nil', 'hammarström', 'Johan', 'nil', 'hamraoui', 'yassine', 'nil']

Comment: Your data should look like this [ ('Klis', 'Martijn', 'nil'), ('der', 'Sloot', 'Sander'),('dns-admin', 'nil', 'nil')]

Comment: can you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for all your help, I was able to find the solution and here it is:

```
it = iter(updated_values[7:-1])
updated_values_1 = list(zip(it, it, it))
query = "INSERT INTO names(last_name, first_name, titles) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(query,updated_values_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data = []
first_names = data[::3]
last_names = data[1::3]
titles = data[2::3]
x = 0

for first_name in first_names:
   new_data.append( (first_names, last_names[x], titles[x] ))
   x += 1

query = "INSERT INTO names(last_name, first_name, titles) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(query,new_data)
```

Basically separate your data then loop through one of the arrays and build a new arrray. This is untested so I'm sure you'll have to modify something.

Comment: Thanks, please check the answer i posted, so basically i iterated through my list and created tuple using zip

Comment: Nice! We all learned something today. I definitely have some use for iter and zip.